# how do I click all href JavaScript links with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple codes on my website like these below, I'm trying to make a small JavaCcript piece of code or jQuery that will automatically click all of these `hrefs` and do the deleteXY functions with the correct numbers.

```
<li><a href="javascript:deleteXY(4)">Delete</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:deleteXY(6)">Delete</a></li>
```

Comment: So select all the elements, loop over them, call click

Comment: you need to have specific class in DOM

Comment: @HardeepSingh you don't really need a specific class to do this..

Comment: why exactly you need to do so? If it's your website, then you can alter your code directly and efficiently. Also BTW, mobile devices create trouble with such click events sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Using Jquery you could to it like this..

```
$('a').each(function(){
   $(this).click();
});
```

Consider that this will affect the entire page so, is better if you use a wrapper, class, or attribute to identify the a tags..

Comment: Instead of `.click()` wouldn't it be more accurate to call the function yourself, by getting the value of the `href` attribute?

Comment: Yes Its an option, which in that case we might need to work, with the href string using regex or string methods..

Comment: `$('a[href*=javascript]')` would select all anchors with javascript href.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `JavaScript`

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
  a[i].click();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript

```
function clickall() {
    var a = document.links, i = 0;
    while( a[i] )a[i++].click();
}
```